# Excel Ribbon XML how to do a control like the Excel "Pivot Table" control

Tags: excel, interop, vsto, ribbon, excel-dna

I would like to create a Control like the Pivot-Table in an Add-In XML ribbon.

It's like a clickable button at the top and a dropdown Label opening a menu.
Using the VSTO ribbon designer I am not able to reproduce it.

In fact what I need is the XML for this control.
Any idea ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're seeing a *splitButton* control, which needs to have exactly two children:

- a *button* or *toggleButton*, and
- a *menu*.

In this case the *splitButton* has an image set (the pivot table picture) and a child *button* (with the label 'PivotTable'). The *menu* then has two children, the two *buttons* below called PivotTable and PivotChart.

An xml fragment might look like this:

```
          <splitButton id='split' size='large'>
                <button id='splitButton' label='SplitButton' image='M'  />
                <menu id='splitMenu' >
                  <button id='splitMenuButton1' label='SplitMenuButton1' />
                  <button id='splitMenuButton2' label='SplitMenuButton2' />
                </menu>
          </splitButton>
```

giving me this in Excel:

[image: splitButton in Excel]

Comment: saved by Govert, again :)

Comment: If you works, you can 'Accept' the Answer - there should be a check mark somewhere.